# My computer keeps freezing. What could it be?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, freeze

So, basically my computer freezes very often, when I'm surfing on the web or just browsing my files, all of a sudden it freezes. I can't do anything unless I force it to shut down and restart. Also, sometimes it freezes while booting. And the OS is not running smoothly, animations are lagging, windows take a bit to open.

I realized it's not the OS because I was using it with Windows 10 and now I tried Ubuntu (the OS that came installed), but it freezes anyway.
This wasn't happening before (I used Ubuntu, Windows 7, Windows 8 and recently Windows 10, and again Ubuntu... Yeah, this PC is kind of old).

Well, I don't know much about hardware, so I hope you guys can guide me with this issue.
is it better to fix it or buy another computer?
Thank you guys in advance.

---

Here, the **motherboard specifications** I found online:
Motherboard: PCWare APMCP61-D3 DDR3

- Manufacturer product code: APMCP61-D3
- Shape: Micro-ATX
- Chipset: NVIDIA MCP61
- Dimensions: 24,4 x 21,4 cm

Chipset:
- North bridge: GeForce 6150SE
- South bridge: nForce 430

Compatible processors:
- Transfer: 2000 MT/s
- socket: AM3
- AMD Phenom II
- AMD Athlon II
- AMD Sempron 140
- AMD Sempron 145

Memory:
- 2 slot DDR3 dual channel (240 pins)
- DDR3 1333/1066/800 MHz support
- Memory maximum capacity: 8 GB

Expansion Slots:
- 1 slot PCI Express x16
- 1 slot PCI Express x1
- 2 slots PCI conventional

Integrated video:
- Chipset: NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE Graphics
- It's own chipset. Does not degrade the performance of the machine.
- Connector: VGA

Network:
- Chipset: Realtek RTL8201EL-GR
- It's own chipset. Does not degrade the performance of the machine.
- Connector: RJ-45
- Speed: 10/100 Mbps

Audio:
- Integrated audio with connector (internal) S/PDIF
- Chipset: VIA VT1705
- It's own chipset. Does not degrade the performance of the machine.
- 5.1 channel system

Rear pannel:
- 1 connector PS/2 for keyboard
- 1 connector PS/2 for mouse
- 1 serial port
- 1 VGA port
- 4 2.0 USB ports
- 1 RJ-45 network port
- 2 audio output, for microphone, speakers
- 1 sound input

Internal connectors:
- 1 24-pin ATX power connector.
- 1 ATX12V 4-pin auxiliary connector
- 1 FAN CPU connector
- 1 SYS FAN connector
- 1 front panel connector
- 1 audio front panel connector
- 1 SPDIF output connector
- 4 SATAII 3.0 Gb / s ports
- 1 IDE connector
- 1 FDD connector
- 3 USB 2.0 connectors (providing 6 ports via cable)
- 1 connector for Intrusion Sensor (Intrusion Chassis)

---

**Specifications in a sticker on CPU**:
Processor: X4-840
OS: Linux Ubuntu
Memory: 4GB (I added another 4GB, so 8GB in total)
Hard drive: 1TB
Optical unit: DVD recorder
Other units:
Video Interface:Onboard video
Network Interface: Onboard network
[photo of the hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKvxW.jpg)

Comment: Using a suitable app e.g. CrystalDiskInfo on Windows check the health of the hard disk/SSD whatever you have. Any bad sectors on the disk might be a possible reason for freezes. Also run the system with just 1 RAM stick and alternate between the two. A faulty RAM might also cause this. Check the CPU for temperature. A system that's overheating might even freeze or abruptly shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple thing to do when something like this happens is to open the case and check if the cooler of the cpu needs thermal paste.

When the cpu needs more thermal paste you can start to get more cpu usage even when idle and you would get this symptoms you write.

Also you can check if ram is in the slot as it should be.

This is a something you can try and does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Firsty thing to do - Check motherboard for bios updates. If none, reset bios to factory settings - ensure that you remember your SATA settings. Most computers these days use AHCI mode.

Use only half the ram you have. Use one stick at a time and try to recreate the fault.

Check Event Viewer to see if there are any clues to the lock-up around the time of the lock-up.

Try another power supply.

Reseat the processor and apply fresh thermal paste for the heatsink.

If possible, try another processor - does not need to be the same, but compatible with your motherboard.

Try entirely different ram  same spec.

Install another HDD and install lubuntu. This is a light version of ubuntu which demands a lot less from your hardware. See if the problem disappears.

PC Hang troubleshooting demands a lot of swapping components/devices/software/disks but as long as you make notes as you go concerning what you have done so far you should get a result.

Notes may sound over the top, but it is very easy to forget to replace something and then come to the wrong conclusion.